# multidimensional array sort based on database column value compare

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have following multidimensional array

```
Array
(

    [1] => 22
    [2] => 12
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 21
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 3
        )

    [7] => 7
    [8] => 6
    [9] => 1
    [10] => 2
    [11] => 10
    [12] => 0
    [13] => 23
    [14] => 18
    [15] => 16
    [16] => 19
    [17] => 15
    [18] => 5
    [19] => 8
    [20] => 11
    [21] => 13
    [22] => 17
    [23] => 14
    [24] => 20
)
```

I want to sort morethan one value below array from main array.

```
Array
(

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 21
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 3
        )
)
```

Each key value compare with database column and sort an array. If not found value then array keep as it is. 
For example:
 The below key value is 21 have in database column then am expected results as,

```
[3] => Array
    (

        [0] => 21
        [1] => 4

    )
```

look as next array, the next array key value not found in the database then expected results as it is,

```
[5] => Array
    (

        [0] => 9
        [1] => 3

    )
```

The final output look for,

```
Array
(

    [1] => 22
    [2] => 12
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
            [1] => 4
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 3
        )

    [7] => 7
    [8] => 6
    [9] => 1
    [10] => 2
    [11] => 10
    [12] => 0
    [13] => 23
    [14] => 18
    [15] => 16
    [16] => 19
    [17] => 15
    [18] => 5
    [19] => 8
    [20] => 11
    [21] => 13
    [22] => 17
    [23] => 14
    [24] => 20
)
```

Could you please help me

Comment: `rsort($array[3])` ??

Comment: The key value 21 is hour of the day. This hours should match with database column like,

I want to retrieve the industry time value from database

Comment: foreach($array as $key=>$val) {
 $sql = "select time from table where industryid=$id";
 $row = mysql_fetch_row();
 if($row['time']==$val) {
  // Want to store as seperate array right
  
 } else {
 
 }

}

Comment: I  does not idea for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this.

```
$dump_array=Array('1' => 2,'2' => 12,'3' => Array
    ('0' => 8,'1' => 21 ),
'5' => Array ('0' => 9,'1' => 3),
'7' => 7,
'8' => 64,
'9' => 15,
'10' => 22,

    );
echo "<pre> Soure :"; print_r($dump_array);echo "</pre>";
sort($dump_array);
$result_array=array();
$array_unlist=array();
foreach($dump_array as $key=>$value){
    if(is_array($value)){
        sort($value);
        array_push($array_unlist,$value);
    }
    else {array_push($result_array,$value);}
}
foreach($result_array as $index=>$val){
    foreach($array_unlist as $key=>$digit){
        if($val<$digit[0])
        {
            $res=$index.".5";
            $result_array[$res]=$digit;
        }
    }
}

ksort($result_array);

echo "<pre> Result :"; print_r(array_values($result_array));echo "</pre>";
```

output:

```
 Soure :Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 12
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 21
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 3
        )

    [7] => 7
    [8] => 64
    [9] => 15
    [10] => 22
)
 Result :Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 9
        )

    [2] => 7
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 21
        )

    [4] => 12
    [5] => 15
    [6] => 22
    [7] => 64
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach($array as $k => $v){

        if(is_array($v)){

         rsort($array[$k]); 

        }

}

print_r($array);
```